# I need to write a JPQL query which returns the elements that contains all listed tags

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two entity

`@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz_questions")
public class QuizQuestion {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonView(ShortSummary.class)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
@JsonView(ShortSummary.class)
private String title;

@Column(name = "text", nullable = false, length = 4096)
@JsonView(ShortSummary.class)
private String text;

 /**
 * List of tags, which include the question
 */
@JoinTable(name = "quiz_questions_tags",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_question_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,   CascadeType.MERGE}) // do not add PERSIST
@JsonView(ShortSummary.class)
private Set<Tag> tags;
```

}
`
and

`@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "tag")
private String tag;
```

}`

I need to write a query that returns a list of questions to which there are ALL of these tags.
In repository I have method

```
 @Query("SELECT DISTINCT q FROM QuizQuestion q JOIN q.tags u WHERE u IN :tags  ") // working, but the output even if one tag is associated with the question
   List<QuizQuestion> findTag (@Param("tags") Set<Tag> tags);
```

I do not know how to write correctly this request. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
select q from QuizQuestion q where (
    select count(tag.id) 
    from QuizQuestion q2 
    inner join q2.tags tag 
    where q2.id = q.id
    and tag.id in :requiredTagIds) 
= :requiredTagCount
```

where `requiredTagIds` is the set of IDs of required tags, and `requiredTagCount` is the size of this set.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I rewrote the request and all works

Comment: `@Query("select q from QuizQuestion q where (select count(q2.id) from QuizQuestion q2" +
           " inner join q2.tags tag where q2.id = q.id and tag.id in :requiredTagIds group by q2.id) = :requiredTagCount")
   List<QuizQuestion> findTag (@Param("requiredTagIds") Set<Integer> requiredTagIds, @Param("requiredTagCount") Long requiredTagCount );`